# JQuery getJSON Callback Returning Null Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, null, getjson

I have a getJSON call that is called back correctly, but the data variable is null. The python code posted below is executed by the getJSON call to the demandURL. Any ideas?

javascript:

```
var demandURL = "/demand/washington/";
$.getJSON(demandURL, function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

python:

```
data = {"demand_count":"one"}
json = simplejson.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the request in Fiddler to verify that response body is indeed valid json?

Comment: try to hit your ajax url directly in browser see what you get

Comment: i dont have any experience with PYTHON , but cleary either u r not hitting the correct server URL or u r not returning the data correctly from server side , take a quick check

Answer (score 0):

Switch out your getJSON with an ajax call so you can have a look at the error message. Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```